# Which of these verbs match to the following context?

Tags: word-choice

I don't find a specific topic in a huge book, and I want help from my friend.

Which of the following verbs match to the situation?

> 1) Please, **turn** me to the correct page in the book, in which this
>   topic is located.
>
> 2) Please, **direct** me to the correct page in the book, in which
>   this topic is located.
>
> 3) Please, **divert** me to the correct page in the book, in which
>   this topic is located.
>
> 4) Please, **refer** me to the correct page in the book, in which this
>   topic is located.
>
> 5) Please, **allocate** me to the correct page in the book, in which
>   this topic is located.

Comment: Do you want to keep the rest of the sentence as it is or are you open to other constructions?

Comment: Absolutely open minded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are many ways to say this. If your friend already knows you are talking about a book (and not a magazine for example) and which book it is, then you don't have to say "in the book" when asking the question.

> 1) Please, **turn** me to the correct page in the book, in which this topic is located.

I don't think "turn **me** to" works in this case. *"Turn me"* works in *"turn me in"*, *"turn me on"*, and *"turn me into"*. They are used for very different things and have different meanings. <s>You could use *"turn to"* though.</s>

---

**Edit:** The phrase ***"turn to"*** is typically used when *we are telling someone* to look at a particular page. It isn't usually used to *ask someone* to tell us what page something is on.

---

> (a) I want to read about the demise of the Gigantopithecus. Which page should I turn to? *{This usage is very unusual and may even be unidiomatic}*
>
> From Cambridge, **"turn"** (change position) means *to move, or to move an object or page, so that a different side or surface is on the top*.
>
> *"Now turn to (= open the book at) page 23 and look at the first paragraph."*

Your second version

> 2) Please, **direct** me to the correct page in the book, in which this topic is located.

seems to be more widely used when referring to websites or web pages.

> From Cambridge, **"direct"** (say where) means *to tell someone how to get somewhere*.

To me, *"direct"* seems more appropriate for a situation when finding something (other than a physical location) is more difficult than say finding a topic in a simple book (e.g., trying to find a specific regulation in a Health Act/legislation or trying to find something specific in a journal with hundreds of articles from different authors). However, since you mention it is a huge book, you can use *"direct"* if what you are looking for is a very specific content. I could find very few usages in google: *"...can you direct me to the page in the manual..."* and [*"Could you direct me to the page, sir?"*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hIbYWclLsYUC&pg=RA1-PA40&lpg=RA1-PA40&dq=%22direct%20me%20to%20the%20page%22&source=bl&ots=IMpZgy2UfW&sig=ACfU3U0S_la4NXzPozBQ0qYdUzjjku_i1w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNgaCejd7lAhXRup4KHRIVAhwQ6AEwBHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22direct%20me%20to%20the%20page%22&f=false). You could ask

> (b) Can you please direct me to where I can find the write-up on the first sighting of the Gigantopithecus?
>
> Sure, it's in page 302, last paragraph.

I don't think

> 3) and 5) Please, **divert/allocate** me to the correct page in the book, in which this topic is located.

are correct. They mean something very different than what you are looking for.

> 4) Please, **refer** me to the correct page in the book, in which this topic is located.

You may be able to use *"refer"* here, but the sentence would need to be rephrased and reworded.

> From Cambridge, the phrasal verb [**"refer (sb) to sth"**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refer-sb-to-sth) means *to look at, or tell someone else to look at, a book or similar record in order to find information and help*.
>
> *"He referred to a history book to find out the dates of the French Revolution."*
>
> From Collins, *if you refer someone to a source of information, you tell them the place where they will find the information which they need or which you think will interest them.*
>
> *"Mr Bryan also referred me to a book by the American journalist Anthony Scaduto."*

Here are some examples from google books:

> [*"Can you refer me to the page of the evidence in which he says that he ..."*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=GCsrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22can%20you%20refer%20me%20to%20the%20page%22&source=bl&ots=jybH8ATlZA&sig=ACfU3U2ZSYNHGJ8KZthWw7cm5o4RhB4u3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH6MHBmN7lAhWcJTQIHU2mAVoQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22can%20you%20refer%20me%20to%20the%20page%22&f=false)
>
> [*"... can you refer me to the page in the Report or Accounts in which it appears?"*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xGwTAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA3-PA59&lpg=RA3-PA59&dq=%22can%20you%20refer%20me%20to%20the%20page%22&source=bl&ots=fU9d3Nlhwb&sig=ACfU3U00PIXLt-QrzrCiRxjq7nd69oXdeg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH6MHBmN7lAhWcJTQIHU2mAVoQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ)
>
> [*"Can you refer me to the page of Wilson in which he speaks of what is necessary bed-space?"*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=uUZRAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=%22can%20you%20refer%20me%20to%20the%20page%22&source=bl&ots=JFhkeWw-IO&sig=ACfU3U2Ab9un3Gaop2FZQOcTmX2HYt0sFw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH6MHBmN7lAhWcJTQIHU2mAVoQ6AEwBXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22can%20you%20refer%20me%20to%20the%20page%22&f=false)

You could say

> (c) Can you please refer me to the page that talks about the eating habits of the Gigantopithecus?

---

Here are some other options.

> Where is the part on the discovery of the remains of Gigantopithecus in East Asia?
>
> On which page can I find ...?